# Stop rollout android application update in new Console

Tags: android, google-play

We have unfortunatelly released a buggy version in Play console. Few hundreds of users have already downloaded this version. While developers are working on a fix I want to stop publishing this update. But there is no Advanced screen in new Google Console. Is there some way how to stop update? All questions describe old APK screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot stop the update.
However, you could just roll out the latest non-buggy version with a changed version number.
Using the new publishing you can specify how many users (in percent) receive the update; It might be possible to stop the update then - but I might be wrong on that (and in the worst case only a fraction of your users receive the buggy version)

Edit to add:
Using staged rollouts (where you specify which % of users shold receive the update) the rollout can be cancelled. New installs or users which haven't update yet won't receive the stopped version, but users which have already updated won't be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new release it gives the option to retain apk's or bundles that are still pending publication. I think the rollout continues but with the new update. I just did it a minute ago.